# Wordpress, display item in specific row

Tags: php, wordpress

working on a site, and I have some difficulties. It's really hard or not done by php what I am trying to accomplish!

So, there is a section named 'references', and each item belongs to a row (out of 4 rows).

At my static page it looks like this:

```
<div id="references-tiles">
        <div class="reference">
          <div class="reference-figure malmberg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="reference">
            <div class="reference-figure malmberg"></div>
        </div>
    ****<div class="references-row"></div>****
        <div class="reference">
          <div class="reference-figure port"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="reference">
            <div class="reference-figure malmberg"></div>
        </div>
    ****<div class="references-row"></div>****

        <div class="reference">
            <div class="reference-figure malmberg"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The reference-row acts like a separator
[image]

Each reference has to be a post, unfortunately wordpress won't work this way

Loop through Post and display them one the same way (only the items)

```
        <div id="references-tiles">
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'References' ) );

            if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
                <div class="reference">
                   <div class="reference-figure" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
```

[image]

I just can't figure out how to control in a way, that a reference item is added to a row.
I tried using some modulo statements like:

```
if ($referenceCount % 4 == 0)
elseif ($referenceCount % 3 == 0)
elseif ($referenceCount % 2 == 0)
else
```

But this wasn't working out because as long I am in the loop, each item can be devided but not added in an already existing row.

Is there a way? Maybe to loop through the loop, add each reference item in a array, and depending on how many items total, I can devid them. Or use the loop 4 times and depending on the modulo, add a reference-item to a row? But I guess this wil make the site a bit slower..

Sorry for bad English, I am not clear at al, I am happy to try en explain myself better!

Regards and thanks!
IT-student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a counter to your loop.

```
<div id="references-tiles">
    <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'References' ) );

                // Add a counter vvvvv
    if ($query->have_posts()) : $i = 1; while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
        <div class="reference">
           <div class="reference-figure" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- If the counter is evenly divisible by 2, add a new row -->
        <?php if ( $i % 2 === 0 ) : ?>
            <div class="references-row"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Increment the counter -->
    <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this wil give every item a row on its own, but not sure. Going to test thinks out now thanks

Comment: If this still displays items on their own...you're experiencing a CSS issue. There's nothing wrong with the loop above.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to work! Just have to fine tune it so it'll show 4 rows with the figures evenly divided

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) on the returned `$query` array

**NOTE:** The examples uses foundation's grid system to better display the outcome.

```
<?php 
/**
 * The second argument for array_chunk takes the size of the chunks
 * ie: the number of columns you want to display per row
 */
$columnsPerRow = 4;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'References' ) );

if($query->have_posts()) : foreach(array_chunk($query->get_posts(), $columnsPerRow) as $posts) : ?>

<div class="row">
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="columns small-6 medium-4">
        <?php 
         /**
          * Fetch the post thumbnail
          * to be used as a background
          */
         $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )); 
         ?>
        <div class="panel" style='background:url("<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>")'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- end row -->

<?php 
 endforeach;
 endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, not using foundation but i am going to try this out!

Comment: Did you downvote, and if so, could you explain why please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a counter, wordpress has a counter as it is in their loop.

```
<?php if ($query->current_post%2) { ?>
    <div class="references-row"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Make sure this code is inside the loop and before the endwhile.

Comment: Ow really? Didn't know that one, thanks for that! But I already used this (with counter) and the result hereby is: every item gets its own row, but I need to have a couple of results in one row

Comment: Keep in mind that `$current_post` starts at `0`. You should consider adding `1` to it, otherwise the first `references-row` won't be displayed until after the third post.

Comment: Yes, ill understand. But in this case, if a modulo statement is correct it will but al previous reference in one row (correct me if i am wrong). I need the total amount of reference-post devided into the 4 rows

Comment: Did you downvote, and if so, could you explain why please?